# Adding records to the table programatically

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

i am trying to append some records from a certain table to a new table ,
when i try it i am unable to append to the values 
to the new table i.e "Table1" in this case what might be the reason for the data not getting appended to the table?

Comment: Which line gives you the error, please?

Comment: i have cleared the error but now i am unable to write the contents to the table

Comment: Your select statement is missing a space between `Input_TBL.COMPANY` and `FROM`.  Is that just an error in pasting the code?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code you are just appending records from one table in your database into another table in the same database. You don't need to use a Recordset object to accomplish this; an INSERT INTO query will accomplish what you want.

```
Dim strSQL as String
Dim db as DAO.Database

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( UPI, COMPANY ) " & _
         "SELECT INPUT_TBL.ID, INPUT_TBL.COMPANY FROM INPUT_TBL"

db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Set db = Nothing
```

Note that I used CurrentDb for the db object, under the assumption that the current database is the same one at C:\Users\test.accdb. If that's not the case, then you will need to do one of two things:

1. If you can add both of these tables as linked tables to the database you are running this code in, you can just use the same code as above. Instructions on how to add tables from an external database to your current database are available here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-HA001227658.aspx#BM3 and many other places on the internet.
2. If you can't add linked tables to your database for some reason, you can add IN clauses to the previous SQL string, which would become:

   ```
   Dim strSQL as String
   Dim db as DAO.Database
   Dim dbname as String

   Set db = CurrentDb

   dbname = "C:\Users\test.accdb"

   strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table1 ( UPI, COMPANY ) IN """ & dbname & """ " & _
            "SELECT INPUT_TBL.ID, INPUT_TBL.COMPANY FROM INPUT_TBL IN """ & dbname & """"

   db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

   Set db = Nothing
   ```

   This code would allow you select the data from Table1 in the external database and add it to INPUT_TBL in the same external database.

Comment: hi viking what if i want to alter a row in my output table say suppose i have Debit_credit and Amount  field  the amount field corresponds to either debit or credit in my table and if the value is C or D then i would like to seggregate amount based on debit or credit. how can this be done in sql insert into. If there is a record set we can use it like if rs(0)=D then rs![debit]=rs(3)[where 3 is amount filed] else rs![credit] =0how can this be done in Inset statement

Comment: Do the C or D values indicate anything other than whether the amount field should be treated as a credit or debit?

Comment: got the solution a simple IIf in sql made my day thank you viking